# How do I select an SVG inside an `object` tag?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Here's how HTML page's contents look.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="Map-edited.svg"></object>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's how `script.js` looks.

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text("Hello");

var svg=    d3.select("object").select("svg");
svg.selectAll('g')
    .on("mouseover",function(){
        return tooltip.style("visibility","visible");
    })
    .on("mousemove",function(){
        var offset=         20;
        var topPosition=    (event.pageY-offset)+"px";
        var leftPosition=   (event.pageX+offset)+"px";
        return tooltip.style("top",topPosition).style("left",leftPosition);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(){
        return tooltip.style("visibility","hidden");
    });
```

When I open my HTML page, I see the SVG element with all the `g` elements in it. When I mouseover each `g` element, no tooltip appears. But if I replace `object` with the `svg` tag and its contents, the tooltip works. How do I make d3 select an SVG in an `object` tag?

Comment: Events on  **<g>** element are only works when there is something under the pointer which belong to this  **<g>** element, such as "circle", "rect", "path".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to access the `<object>` [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) in order to access its contained elements.

To do this, you also need to wait until your `<object>` has loaded its content.

I'm not too much into d3, so it might not be the best d3 way of doing, but at least it works:
<sub>(but not in StackSnippet's null origined iframes...)</sub>

```js
fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg')
  .then(r => r.blob())
  .then(b => obj.data = URL.createObjectURL(b));

obj.onload = function() { // wait for the svg has loaded

  var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text("Hello");

  var obj = this; // we're in the object's load event handler.
  var svg = d3.select(obj.contentDocument) // get the contentDocument
    .select("svg"); // then get the svg inside
  svg.selectAll('g')
    .on("mouseover", function() {
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function() {
      var event = d3.event;
      var offset = 20;
      var topPosition = (event.pageY - offset) + "px";
      var leftPosition = (event.pageX + offset) + "px";
      return tooltip.style("top", topPosition).style("left", leftPosition);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
    });

};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<object id="obj" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

#### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lembynv6/1)

Comment: *"D3 seems rather useless here..."* There is where you show that in fact you're not too much into D3: a D3 selection and a DOM element are different things.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I was talking about `d3.select('...').node()` which returns a DOM element (that I already gained access to before in the script, for unrelated reasons). And I hope you meant *indeed* rather than *in fact*  because I never pretended to be into d3, rather the contrary.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, I completely changed this line, to show you that this call was **indeed** absolutely not needed.

Comment: I was just telling you that `d3.select(whatever)` does not return the "whatever" DOM element, but I regret having left a comment.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes because I never said so. I'm not too much on d3 in the sense that there might be built-ins I don't know to access the contentDocument, but I know it enough to know what is returned by d3.select.

Comment: This gave enough of a clue to help solve a little issue - thanks for that!#

Answer (score 4):

**I have no experience with d3 but this might help.**
You need to wait untill your window is fully loaded.

```
// object of my SVG
<object id="fridge" data={FridgePicture} ></object>

window.onload = function() {
    // Get the fridgeObject by ID
    var fridgeObj = document.getElementById("fridge");
    // Get the SVG document inside the Object tag
    var fridgeDoc = fridgeObj.contentDocument;
    // From here you can get an item you wish e.g:
    var rightDoor = fridgeDoc.getElementById("RightDoor");
};
```

Comment: That's very useful. Thanks! The number of different functions one has to learn in order to extract SVGs and their components is insane. So little examples like this really help.

Answer (score 0):

Just a short summery which methods work and which won't:

```
  d3.select(obj.node().contentDocument).select('svg').selectAll('g') // get the contentDocument
  console.log('node > svg > g => works!',nsvg)

  var obj1 = d3.select('#obj'); // we're in the object's load event handler.
  var ng = d3.select(obj1.node().contentDocument).selectAll('g') // get the contentDocument
  console.log('node > g => works!',ng)

  var obj2 = d3.select('#obj'); // we're in the object's load event handler.
  var svg = d3.select(obj2.contentDocument).select('svg').selectAll('g') // get the contentDocument
  console.log('select svg > g => fails!',svg)

  var obj3 = d3.select('#obj'); // we're in the object's load event handler.
  var g = d3.select(obj3.contentDocument).selectAll('g') // get the contentDocument
  console.log('select g => fails!',g)

  var getElement = document.getElementById('obj').contentDocument
  var gElements = d3.select(getElement).select('svg').selectAll('g')
  console.log("gElements > d3.select svg > g => works!", gElements);

  var svg2 = document.getElementById('obj').contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('g')
  console.log("getElementById => works!", svg2);
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hirschferkel/0wu3z1st/11/