# Import an SVG file using JavaScript and then animate it with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to import a SVG file using JavaScript and animate the graphic with CSS.
I'm able to import the file but

```
cursor: pointer
```

doesn't work and I'm not able to access the SVG graphics attributes like fill or totalPathLenght.
Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

1. I tried importing the SVG like this:

```
const myGraphic = document.createElement("object");
myGraphic.data = "mySVG.svg";
document.body.appendChild(myGraphic);
```

2. I also tried the same thing using iframe and embed

Comment: You can't change styles of an `<object>`, `<embed>` or `<iframe>` directly. See this question [How do I select an SVG inside an `object` tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839536/how-do-i-select-an-svg-inside-an-object-tag). As you're creating the object dynamically - why don't you append your svg as an inlined DOM element?

Answer (score 0):

A good explanation on how to do this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9873113/6456163), I'll paraphrase and adapt it for what you are asking:

```js
const svgElement = document.getElementById("svg");
const checkboxElement = document.getElementById("check");

checkboxElement.addEventListener("change", e => {
  svgElement.style.fill = e.target.checked ? "PeachPuff" : "PapayaWhip";
});
```

```css
#svg {
  /* An example of how to set the cursor */
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<svg id="svg" fill="AliceBlue">
  <circle r="50" cx="70" cy="70" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i wanted to import a already existing SVG using JavaScript.

Comment: @MarkoMiklas it's the exact same premise, I just can't give you a demo without access to your image.